Java Json date parse
not able to get out of this error
 Text '2024-03-28T09:07:55.896198Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 26
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:600)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:53)

Im getting from API response where one of the fields are       "published_at": "2024-03-20T09:12:53.304420Z", im trying to filter the response so that it give only data from 1. june 2022 till 1.april 2024. So far i tried several parse formats, and always similar error.
  try {
            HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
            String responseBody = response.body();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    ArrayNode offersArray = mapper.createArrayNode();
                    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(responseBody);
            JsonNode offers = rootNode.path("offers");

                    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 6, 1);
                    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2024, 4, 1);
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;

            for (JsonNode offer : offers) {
                String publishedAtStr = offer.path("published_at").asText();
//                LocalDate publishedAt = LocalDate.parse(publishedAtStr, formatter);
                ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(publishedAtStr, formatter);
                LocalDate publishedAt = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate();

                if ((publishedAt.isAfter(startDate) || publishedAt.isEqual(startDate)) &&
                        (publishedAt.isBefore(endDate) || publishedAt.isEqual(endDate))) {
                    ObjectNode offerNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
                    offerNode.put("title", offer.path("title").asText());
                    offerNode.put("description", offer.path("description").asText());
                    offerNode.put("location", offer.path("location").asText());
                    offerNode.put("requirements", offer.path("requirements").asText());
                    offerNode.put("published_at", publishedAtStr);

                    offersArray.add(offerNode);
                }
            }


Why are you trying to parse a ZonedDateTime using a formatter intended for LocalDateTime? If you don't pass a formatter at all, the ZonedDateTime can parse your sting successfully, i.e. ZonedDateTime.parse("2024-03-28T09:07:55.896198Z") works ok.

BTW in ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME the LOCAL indicates it does not know about time zones (as Local does for LocalDateTime), so it will fail when parsing that string since it has time zone information (Z) - it should be parsed with ISO_DATE_TIME, which that is the default, as described in previous comment

So, change to ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(publishedAtStr); I don't know if it's just me, but does anyone else find it astonishing that, with java.time we still need to do something like if ((publishedAt.isAfter(startDate) || publishedAt.isEqual(startDate)) && (publishedAt.isBefore(endDate) || publishedAt.isEqual(endDate)))??

java.time exception messages are often quite helpful. Yours says: "... unparsed text found at index 26". Did you count your way to where index 26 is in your string? The documentation is another place to look. Did you read the documentation of DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME; (it’s a link)? If you didn’t or you didn’t undersatnad it, that’s fair. In any case tell us what search and research you have already done before asking the question.

This string 2024-03-28T09:07:55.896198Z is an ISO 8601 date string, so you could use Instant.parse(publishedAtStr) to parse it.
LocalDateTime can parse some ISO 8601 formats, but it fails when there is a time zone indicator (which is the character Z at index 26), so instead of coming up with a pattern yourself, simply use the Instant class.
On a side note, JSON has nothing to do with this problem at all.
